# Filter a list of objects using computed properties?

Tags: ember.js

Short context - I am using ember and ember-data to present a list of events to a user. Events are aggregated in the API endpoint, and each even has a "kind" property that notes what type the event is (announcement, etc). Events are filtered at the api level by user (so you have to query on a user_id to get the user's list of events.

I need to display all these events on a single page, but break them up by kind. There's a fixed list of kinds, so we can just call them A and B.

My intuition is to set up the model in the EventsRoute like so:

```
model: function () {
 return this.store.find('events', {user_id: $.cookie('user_id')});
}
```

and then make the various event types be filters on EventsController:

```
announcements: function() {
  return this.get('model').filterBy('kind', 'announcement');
}.property(),
```

This works, at least in my test cases. I'm not sure it's the right way to go about things, though. I haven't quite grokked the difference between properties (which seem to be set on the controller) and the model (which the route sets). So, my questions are:

1. Is this the right way to go about creating filtered sublists of data? Should I not rely on the .get('model') call to pull the underlying data?
2. Should the property() call actually name anything? These should be recomputed when the underlying model changes, but as far as I can tell, ember is quiet when you pass in garbage to the property() call ({}.property('potato') doesn't fail), so I don't know if .property('model') or .property('@each') is appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the right way to go about creating filtered sublists of data? Should I not rely on the .get('model') call to pull the underlying data?

Yes this is the right way to do it. Since this is an ArrayController you can use .get('model') or .get('content') to access the array.

> Should the property() call actually name anything?

Yes it should list dependencies that cause the property to be recomputed. For sure ember is quiet if they don't exist. In this case you should use `.property('model.@each.kind')`